# iphone sdk syntax

Tags: iphone, objective-c, syntax

This is probably a really basic syntax question, but I can't find the answer.

Can anyone tell me what this expression means?

```
objPoint.x = -objPoint.x;
```

As a note, objPoint is a CGPoint

Thanks!

Comment: That isn't "iPhone SDK syntax," it's C, C++ or Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You change the horizontal coordination to its negative.

Another example is that:

```
x = 7;
x = -x;
```

Then it will become `x = -7;`

This is the evaluation process:

The evaluation process will be ran in the right hand side first, so the process is:

```
replace x with 7, the right hand side of -x will become -7.
```

then assign it to the left hand side: `x = -7;`

Comment: Thanks for some editting, but I mean because x = 7 so -x = - (7)

Comment: What does that last statement return? What does `(-7 == (-x = -(7)))` evaluate to? I'm assuming true, since it will do the assignment then evaluate the expression. Also, will `(-x) = (-7)` compile?

Comment: No, I mean for the expression x = -x, first, the computer will replace x by 7 so the right hand side will become -7. That's what it means for -x = -7